# Stop css from rotating back

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is the CSS I tried:

```
#navlist:hover #left-arrow {
    border-top: 10px solid white;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateX(120.2px) rotate(180deg);
}
```

Should I use jquery to perform the rotation?

Here is what I tried:

```
$('#navlist').find('#left-arrow').hover(function() {
    $(('#navlist').find('#left-arrow')).css('transform', 'translate(200px) rotate(180deg)');
});
```

Comment: First, can you please add your HTML to the question. Second, do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/ct3ekffe/). What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: There are no errors. I just wanted to know how to call that html part in JQUERY. It's just a random question I do not have any html for it.

Comment: It's a bit confusing calling an element with the id `this`, isn't it?

Comment: so you just want the arrow on the right?  the white one?  your floating that arrow left in your css, need to float it right probably.

Comment: You don't need jQuery for that... a simple css 180 degree rotate on hover with a transition: .5s transform will do... kind of like this answer, but the rotate is done over :hover instead of adding a class by javascript

Comment: css will rotate the image back. I do not want that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this....

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
        $('#navlist').hover(function() {
        //do something with this below
            $('#navlist').find('#this').css('transform', 'translate(100px) rotate(100deg)');
        });
    });
```

full html code is below...

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #navlist
            {
                height:60px;
                background-color:#000;
            }
            #this
            {
                height:30px;
                background-color:#f00;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script >
        $(document).ready(function(){       
            $('#navlist').hover(function() {
            //do something with this below
                $('#navlist').find('#this').css('transform', 'translate(100px) rotate(100deg)');
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="navlist">
            <div id="this">

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for your input, but it doesnt work.  I am trying to shift the  white arrow to the right and stop. i.e do not want it to rotate back.

Comment: thank you. very helpful on the jquery i was having trouble with

Comment: who vote my ans down and why plz explain...it worked for the person who asked it and he accepted the ans as well

Answer (score 1):

You are floating the arrow left in your CSS,  float it right and it should end up where you want it.